# How to cancel a Microsoft Team download

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-teams

I have Microsoft teams application, on Windows 7, and have had someone share a 150Gig file for me.  I clicked on it  three times by the look of it - and it appears to be downloading three times as I can see three files in my Downloads folder all of which are slowly increasing in size- If I attempt to open any of these files I get permission denied.

I can see nothing in view downloads in Firefox or internet explorer - Can anyone point me to a method of managing in progress downloads by Microsoft Teams
the Microsoft Teams download tab shows nothing as well

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I found was to quit Teams completely, which removes the file lock(s). You can then remove the files.

There is a request open on the [Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/34913671-download-improvements) regarding download improvements. It currently only has 128 votes (whereas the top rated ones have 10K+), so I am not expecting much in the near future..